# How to use form group and form array inside a table with simultaneous iteration? I have no idea how to handle it inside the template

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-reactive-forms

This will be the output:

[image]

I have no idea how to handle it inside the template

```
 rateCardForm = this.fb.group({
     package: this.fb.group({
         freeDays: this.fb.array([]),
         paidDays: this.fb.array([]),
     }),
 });
```

Comment: Hi Karan. It is not evident what you are trying to achieve. What do you want to happen when you click add? Do you want only one input at a time or more? A little more context and code would really help

Comment: I want more than one inputs at a time.I want table with irritating more than one input in its body.

Comment: from the screenshot, it looks like you have an array of package

Answer (score 0):

As of my understanding of your captured screen:

```
rateCardForm = this.fb.group({
     package: this.fb.array([
      this.fb.group({
         freeDays: [null],
         paidDays: [null],
        })
     ]),
 });
```

For adding a new item into array:

```
Add(){
    var _package=FormArray>this.rateCardForm.controls.package;
       _package.push( 
          this.fb.group({
             freeDays: [null],
             paidDays: [null],
         })
       )
}
```

For Deleting:

```
Delete(index){
   var _package=<FormArray>this.rateCardForm.controls.package;
   if(_package.controls.length>1){
      _package.removeAt(index)
   }
}
```